# How convert list from one to another type using lameda Expression java

Tags: java, spring

I have a list of Entities Employee(Class) which has fields empid, empname,  emprole.salary

```
List<Employee>= getting from database
```

I want to convert it into model list Person(Class) having fields empname, emprole, salary

```
List<Person> person = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

I am able to convert using a `for` loop. However, I want to convert it using lambda expression.

Comment: Why do you need a lambda expression? Is there a problem with the loop?

Comment: Is person super class of Employee?

Comment: I hoped to find a simple duplicate of this, but a little searching didn't find it - hence answering instead. Someone else may well be able to find a duplicate, of course. (Most stream questions I found were rather more involved.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you've got a suitable constructor, it should be as simple as:

```
List<Person> people = employees
    .stream() // View the list as a stream
    .map(e -> new Person(e.getId(), e.getName(), e.getRole().getSalary()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that if that's *all* you're doing with the list of employees, that may well mean you've fetched more data than you actually need. You should look at what the queries are doing and consider tweaking them to only return what you need.